# Why am I getting errors with Cycles baking from materials?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

So I'm fairly familiar with Cycles, but I just ran into some odd issues baking textures - problems that I don't have with Blender Internal.

I want to bake the colours of the materials that I've assigned to faces of my UV-mapped model to a diffuse .png.

In Blender internal (this model is on layer 3 of my file), the baked diffuse looks as I intended:
[image: Blender Internal Bake]

In Cycles (this model is on layer 1 of my file), the baked diffuse (using the same UV layout) is oddly laid out:
[image: Cycles Bake]

My .blend file can be found [here](https://ufile.io/ad9ht).

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening? Much obliged!

--Rev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED

All you have to do is put the *same* image into every texture you're baking:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It seems to work:

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the reply - I've encountered some issues with it, but I've made some progress...!

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for reply - I've encountered issues w/yr notes, but I've made progress...! Was confused by yr instructions (as they seem to suggest I'm baking from one obj to other, whereas I was trying to replicate Blender Internal ability to bake a diffuse tex from mat cols - all on the same obj), but followed 'em & ended up w/a .png that combined both images in my original post. After tests, I duped obj & gave copy only one mat with a target tex (no Tex Coords required). It baked perfectly. Does this mean Cycles cannot bake mat cols to tex on single obj, requires baking selected to active?

Comment: So sorry!!  I misunderstood your question.  The solution is super super simple: just put the bake image in each of the materials.  I edited my answer above.

Comment: Heyyyyy! That makes a ton of sense, especially given the original error results with the materials assigned to the face. I'd prefer that there was a more straightforward method to do this, but it's great that is a solution! Marking correct, thank you Dale!